# Change the Format of Input for a date from Y/M/D to D/M/Y in SQL/PHP from a form

Tags: php, mysql, json, pear, mdb2

I need to be able to change the date format from Y/M/D to D/M/Y. The database with all the data that I am querying has the date set as Y/M/D whereas the input form has the input yet as D/M/Y.

Does anyone have any idea how I can change the format?

***NB the Date is 'DOB'***

**Here is the SQL:**

```html
$sql="SELECT `country_name`,`gdp`,`population`,Cyclist.name,Cyclist.dob FROM Country JOIN Cyclist ON Country.ISO_id=Cyclist.ISO_id 
WHERE 'dob'
BETWEEN '".$date_1."' AND '".$date_2."'";
```

**Here is the PHP for getting the data from the form submission**

```html
$date_1=$_REQUEST['date_1'];
$date_2=$_REQUEST['date_2'];
```

Comment: What is stopping you from parsing the input date any way you want it?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Are you talking about parsing the input from the source form or from the database? Unfortunately, we can't do that? We have to change the datatype  somehow inside the code

Comment: Why can't you just build a `Y-m-d` string inside your PHP code and use that in the query?

Comment: Please do **NOT** edit out your entire post after it has been answered. Accept one of the answers instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STR_TO_DATE parses a string to a date use a given format.

```
$sql="SELECT `country_name`,`gdp`,`population`,Cyclist.name,Cyclist.dob FROM Country JOIN Cyclist ON Country.ISO_id=Cyclist.ISO_id 
WHERE 'dob'
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('".$date_1.",'%d,%m,%Y') AND STR_TO_DATE('".$date_2.",'%d,%m,%Y')'";
```

STR_TO_DATE: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Is there anyway to do it inside the PHP? Such as inside the REQUEST

Comment: Yes, you could do like Pradnya suggested: 

$date_1=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_REQUEST['date_1']));
$date_2=date('d-m-Y', strtotime($_REQUEST['date_2']));

Comment: Thank you! Hopefully it has worked 

Getting issue with output

`$res=& $db->query($sql);
if(PEAR::isError($res)){
  die($res->getMessage());
}

$InputDateArray=array();
echo 'hello';
while($row=$res->fetchRow())
$InputDateArray[] = $row;


echo json_encode($InputDateArray);`

Comment: Sorry, did it work or did something else went wrong?

Comment: I think something else has gone wrong with the output

Comment: check the format of the date that is set to $date_2 and $date_1

Answer (score 0):

You may change the date format in php date() and strtotime() 
e.g: $date_new = date('d-m-Y', strtotime($date));
and then passing it in sql query.